# How do I convert this expression to LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to convert this expression to LINQ?

```
TermsOfPayment termsOfPayment = null;
foreach (CustomerGroup group in _customer.CustomerGroups)
    if (termsOfPayment == null) termsOfPayment = group.TermsOfPayment;
    else if (group.TermsOfPayment != null)
        if (group.TermsOfPayment.InvoiceDueDays < termsOfPayment.InvoiceDueDays)
            termsOfPayment = group.TermsOfPayment;
```

It might seem like a stupid question since the expression above solves the question, but I use some LINQ expressions and am eager to lern more - hence the reason for this post.

Basically I just want to select the TermsOfPayment object with the minimum InvoiceDueDays (integer) value from the groups the customer is a part of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
termsOfPayment = (
                   from g in _customer.CustomerGroups
                   where g.TermsOfPayment != null
                   orderby g.TermsOfPayment.InvoiceDueDays
                   select g.TermsOfPayment
                 ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi, I think your solution was elegant. I'm not sure whether your expression or the one given by @Steven is more efficient, but there won't by many groups to sort anyways. If you update your answer by replacing "group" with "grp","g" or something ("group" is not valid) and add "select g.TermsOfPayment" to the end, I will mark your reply as answered.

Comment: @Vincent: It might be interesting to compare speed with another implementation. `OrderBy` needs to consume the enumerable entirely before sorting. Once done, it will allow us to consume the sorted enumerable. It's done in two pass but I think it describes the behavior better.

Answer (score 1):

```
     var termsOfPayment =
        _customer.CustomerGroups.OrderBy(cg=>cg.TermsOfPayment.InvoiceDueDays)
        .First().Select(cg=>cg.TermsOfPayment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use aggregate, speed is better too:

```
var termsOfPayment = 
    _customer.CustomerGroups.Aggregate((a, n) => n.TermsOfPayment.InvoiceDueDays < a.TermsOfPayment.InvoiceDueDays ? n : a).TermsOfPayment;
```